# Understanding jdbcTemplate for insert and update statements

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

When inserting using jdbctemplate, I am doing this:

getJdbcTemplate().update("insert users (...) values(?,?,?)", user.get...);

1. How do I get the inserted id  back from msql? (it is the primary key)

For updates, is it possible to return a boolean if the update was successful?

```
getJdbcTemplate().update("delete users where id = ?", id);
```

Answer (score 7):

`JdbcTemplate.update()` returns number of rows affected - so you not only know that delete/update was succesfull, you also now how many rows were deleted/updated.

To get generated (from sequence) primary keys, use `org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(PreparedStatementCreator, KeyHolder)` method which allows you to pass e.g. `org.springframework.jdbc.support.GeneratedKeyHolder` which will collect your keys.